# Fastest way to change a 600GB table indexed key datatype from INT to BIGINT

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.5, alter-table

I need to change a datatype from INT to BIGINT in a 600GB MySQL table. The column has a unique index. I might be good with unsigned INT, but I assume changing to that or BIGINT will be pretty much same pain.  The table's engine is InnoDB. What would be easier:

1. ALTER TABLE
2. Copying structure and `INSERT INTO (SELECT *)`
3. Dumping table and changing dump file table definitions
4. Anything else?

UPDATE:
As requested, MySQL ver 5.5.15, no foreign  keys and create table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
    `tid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `t` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `f` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `i_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `ir_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `r_c` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `r` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `e` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `t` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user_id`,`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1657146169 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Define pain, take the shortest amount of time....? Fastest results?

Comment: @AlecTeal Take the shortest amount of time

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question and this question was probbly discussed before the table getting that big, I would also look for a way to reduce this table's size.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? It matters as some versions have `ALTER TABLE ONLINE`. Do you have foreign keys referencing this column? It would help if you showed the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` output.

Comment: @ypercube added to the question.

Comment: If short field names helped reduce table size, it would be 600 *MB*.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades it's actually not the real names, but good one :). you should've noticed there are two t's

Comment: @Noam: I figured as much, it just struck me as funny.  Ah yes, I should have seen those `T`s, I need new glasses.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table does not have any triggers on it, you should consider using [`pt-online-schema-change`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) since it will allow you to ALTER the table without locking it.

It will still take a fair amount of time given the size of the table.

Also, with this method or with `ALTER TABLE` you will need to make sure you have 600 GB of extra disk space to support two copies of the table while it is being rebuilt.

Comment: Got any time estimate? (I know it depends on many factors, but if u had to guess, what would be the range)

Comment: @Noam you don't need to copy the table. If you use Alter table the WORST CASE is that it copies, if you are using a mature engine, it will just make a note to itself that anything before (some location in file or some record) uses int, anything post uses bigint, until you optimise.

Comment: @AlecTeal Do you have any formal reference to that?

Comment: @Noam see my answer.

Comment: @Noam I'd estimate the `ALTER TABLE` could take 24 - 96 hours to run. You can get a better estimate by running the ALTER TABLE in a test environment.

Answer (score 2):

Using percona toolkit `pt-online-schema-change` would be my choice on production without affecting the use. This will add some triggers to get your deltas and a temporal table that would rename after this is done.

example:

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "CHANGE `id` `id` BIGINT  NOT NULL; " D=DB,t=TABLE
```

Comment: pt is the way to go. 
@Noam FYI:

INT->BIGINT migration on a ~270GB table with a lots of rows on EC2 instance with quite heavy write activity on this table took 64hours using pt-online-schema-change.